# The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined (Terraform)

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform configuration which needs to:

1. Create a lambda
2. Invoke the lambda
3. Iterate on the lambda's json result which returns an array and create a CloudWatch event rule per entry in the array

The relevant code looks like:

```
Create lambda code...

data "aws_lambda_invocation" "run_lambda" {
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.deployed_lambda.function_name}"

  input = <<JSON
  {}
  JSON
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.deployed_lambda]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "aws_my_cloudwatch_rule" {
  for_each = {for record in jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.run_lambda.result).entities : record.entityName => record} 
    name = "${each.value.entityName}-event"
    description = "Cloudwatch rule for ${each.value.entityName}"
    schedule_expression = "cron(${each.value.cronExpression})"
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, I get:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on lambda.tf line 131, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "aws_my_cloudwatch_rule":
 131:   for_each = {for record in jsondecode(data.aws_lambda_invocation.aws_lambda_invocation.result).entities : record.entityName => record}

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

I've read a bunch of posts on the problem but couldn't find a workaround.
The problem is that Terraform needs to know the size of the array returned by the lambda in the planning phase before the lambda was created.
What is the best approach to solving such a task?
Since it is run as part of a CI/CD pipeline I prefer a solution that doesn't include the "-target" flag.

Comment: Just as a comment, make sure the aws provider is > 3. I had that error on 2.x and I upgrading the provider fixed it. Also worth mentioning that if yyou do that, it's a major upgrade, so tread carefully.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One possibility is to reconsider **for_each** and use **count** instead, if appropriate. **for_each** has some major limitations. I ran into something similar (seems like a major bug to me, but they say it is a feature)
Consider I am deploying three vms, and want to bind them to a load balancer:

```
resource "aws_instance" "xxx-IIS-004" {

  ami               = var.ami["Windows Server 2019"]
  instance_type     = var.depoy_lowcost ? var.default_instance_type : "m5.2xlarge"
  count             = "3"
  ...
```

When I try to use **for_each**, I get *The “for_each” value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined*...  or Tuple error.

**Fails:**

```
resource "aws_elb_attachment" "attachments_004" {
  depends_on = [ aws_instance.xxx-IIS-004 ]
  elb        = data.aws_elb.loadBalancer.id
  for_each   = aws_instance.xxx-IIS-004[*]
  instance   = each.value.id
}
```

**Works***

```
locals {
  att_004 = join("_", aws_instance.xxx-IIS-004[*].id )
}

resource "aws_elb_attachment" "attachments_004" {
  depends_on = [ aws_instance.xxx-IIS-004 ]
  elb        = data.aws_elb.loadBalancer.id
  count      = length( aws_instance.xxx-IIS-004 )
  instance   = split("_", local.att_004)[count.index]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just move you toward the similar `Error: Invalid count argument` (`The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply`)? Terraform 1.0.3.

Comment: No, because the number of VMs is actually known. I was suggesting use count if appropriate. Tf’s for each has limitations you can get around using count.

Comment: Maybe it works with the specific resource types in the question, but it just wasn't more-broadly usable with all resource types then.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to solve this in pure terraform, the workarounds are at the moment to either split your deployment into multiple stacks/phases (e.g. first deploy a stack with the lambda, and then the second stack that is using the lambda as a data source) or as you already found out, partially deploy your stack using `-target` and then deploy the full stack. (Be sure to remove the `depends_on` in this case as it will defer reading the data source to the apply phase all the time.)

Another option is to use a tool like [terragrunt](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt) that solves the partial apply issue by deploying a set of terraform modules in the right order if all dependencies between those modules are defined. with `terragrunt` you can deploy everything in a single run of e.g. `terragrunt apply-all`. The Downside is you still won't get a nice preview of changes in your CI to be reviewed by your peers.

I would suggest splitting this into two phases as you might actually want to review both before applying the final changes. Else you might end up with a setup where a broken lambda results in destroying all your existing cloudwatch rules ***unnoticed*** by you or your team.

Answer (score 5):

****Some time working****:

```
  resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "attach-in" {
  for_each = toset([for x in module.webserver-in.instance : x.id])
  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.tg-in.arn
  target_id         = each.value
  port             = 443
}
```

****Perfect working****:

```
locals {
  instance_ids = join("_", [for x in module.webserver.instance : x.id] )
       }

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "attach-in" 
{
count = length(module.webserver-in.instance)
target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.tg-in.arn
target_id         = split("_", local.instance_ids)[count.index]
port             = 443
}
```

Comment: Another upvote thanks for mine     resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "RoleAssignment" {
  count = length(var.ResourceIds)
  scope = var.ResourceIds[count.index]
  role_definition_name = var.RoleType
  principal_id         = var.AzureAdPrincipalId
}

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**:
`for_each = toset(var.your_list)`

**Use**:
`for_each = toset(formatlist("%s", range(length(var.your_list))))`

Then you can use the value as `your_list[each.key]`.

---

What you are trying to do isn't supported by `for_each` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#limitations-on-values-used-in-for_each). But here is a little hack to achieve what you are trying to do:

**Explanation**:
Since unknown values are a limitation of `for_each` only, we remove the unknown part from `for_each`. We use:

- `length()` to get number of elements in list.
- `range()` to generate a list such as `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.
- `formatlist()` to convert list items from number to string.
- `var.your_list[each.key]` to iterate over actual items.

Note: I am using `var.your_list` which is a list with unknown values on for simplification, It can be anything, as in your case result from data source.