# How can I fix for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm aware of the similar questions:

- [The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined (Terraform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768921/the-for-each-value-depends-on-resource-attributes-that-cannot-be-determined-t)
- [for_each value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643719/for-each-value-depends-on-resource-attributes-that-cannot-be-determined-until-ap)

but I think mine is a bit different and it might be fixed by refactoring TF code since there's an additional input restriction.

My original example is very long so I came up with a minimum viable example instead:

I've got an input variable of type `map` that maps *all* possible numbers to names:

```
# tfvars.terraform
all_names_by_number = {
  "1" = "alex",
  "3" = "james",
  "5" = "ann",
  "8" = "paul",
}
```

```
# main.tf
locals {
  # active_names_by_number is a map as well
  # but it's a subset of all_names_by_number
  # all_names_by_number = {
  # "3" = "james",
  # "5" = "ann",
  # }
  active_names_by_number = people_resource.example.active_names_map
}

# Resource that depedns on active_names_by_number
resource "foo" "active_items" {
  for_each = local.active_names_by_number

  name                = "abc-${each.key}"
  location            = var.location

  sub_id = data.zoo.sub[each.key].id

  bar {
    bar_name = each.value
  }
}
```

When I run the terraform configuration above via `terraform plan`, I get:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on main.tf line 286, in resource "foo" "active_items":
 286:   for_each = for_each = local.active_names_by_number

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

which totally makes sense since `people_resource.example.active_names_map` is *"initialized"* in runtime from another resource (response)

```
locals {
  active_names_by_number = people_resource.example.active_names_map
}
```

but given the fact that `active_names_by_number` is a subset of `all_names_by_number` (input variable), how can I refactor the terraform configuration to show TF that `local.active_names_by_number` is bounded?

My ideas so far:

1. Use `count` instead of `for_each` as other answers suggest but I do need to use `each.value` in my example (and I can't use `all_names_by_number` to create extra resources.
2. Get rid of `local.active_names_by_number` and use `var.all_names_by_number` instead -- the major downside is TF will create extra resources which is pretty expensive.
3. Somehow write a nested `for` loop:

```
# pseudocode
for name in var.all_names_by_number:
   if name is in people_resource.example.active_names_map:
      # create an instance of foo.active_item
```

Comment: Your question omits the condition based on which that subset is created. How do you decide which name is active? This is important, because you can't rely on `people_resource.example.active_names_map`, but you could create another variable which contains just the active names.

Comment: There's a service that performs _selection_ process during `create` operation (i.e., resource creation) which is why I can't pass it as an input variable.

Comment: You can't do much apart from re-architecting your TF code, so that you create the resources in two steps using `-target` option.

Comment: I also saw a suggestion about splitting it into 2 modules such that `active_names_by_number` will be the output for module #1 and input for module #2, does it sound reasonable? @Marcin

Comment: @AlexKuzminov Yes, its similar to using `-target`. You have to deploy your architecture in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, so I followed the method of splitting it into two modules which @Alex Kuzminov suggested. Thanks for that.

So Instead of using `for_each`, use count and along with that use `try` block.

```
locals {
  active_names_by_number = try(people_resource.example.active_names_map, tolist(["a", "b", "c", "d"]))
}
```

So initial exception will be resolved while terraform apply, then while actual resource running, it will replace with the actual content instead of a,b,c,d.

I hope this helps. Thanks.